WebSocket JS connection work but not from Java Client
Question:
I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket server from a Java application, but the connection works fine with JavaScript code but fails with Java code. Specifically, I receive an HTTP response with status code 400. "I have tried many WebSocket client implementations in Java, but I always get a 400 error, whereas the sample JavaScript code works without any issues. Server application based on Spring framework.
JS Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Your name">
        <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Message">
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.5.0/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var stompClient = null;

        function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8085/gs-guide-websocket/');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (messageOutput) {
                    showMessage(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                });
            });
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
            var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify({'from': from, 'text': text}));
        }

        function showMessage(messageOutput) {
            var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
            var messageElement = document.createElement('li');
            messageElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageOutput.from + ": " + messageOutput.text + " (" + messageOutput.time + ")"));
            messages.appendChild(messageElement);
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            connect();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Java
public class Main {

    // Update the WebSocket URL to match the server configuration
    private static final String URL = "ws://localhost:8085/gs-guide-websocket/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        ListenableFuture<StompSession> future = stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler);

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        future.addCallback(session -> latch.countDown(), ex -> latch.countDown());

        if (latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            StompSession stompSession = future.get();
            System.out.println("Connected to WebSocket server: " + stompSession.isConnected());

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
                String from = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
                String text = scanner.nextLine();
                stompSession.send("/app/chat", new Message(from, text));
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed to connect to WebSocket server within the timeout period.");
        }
    }
}


It was caused set withSockJS after remove it works with Java   registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket")
.setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
.withSockJS()
.setWebSocketEnabled(true);
